# FingerPrint Comparison on server side in PHP

Tags: php, server-side, fingerprint, fingerprinting

**What I have on my plate ready**
In my android mobile app I'm using different third party Android SDK for retrieving fingerprint from respective external fingerprint scanner device (I'm not using inbuilt fingerprint scanner of phone.). I'm able to export and upload fingerprint to my PHP server in RAW format at the time of user enrolment after that at the time of verification I have to download all fingerprints from server to mobile and use respective SDK to compare one by one. Things are working pretty good.

**I am looking for**

Now what I want is to move all FP comparison logic on server side in PHP So I would not have to download all fingerprints on mobile. I will only upload current FP to server and server will compare and reply with Auth status and it will also reduce my dependency on scanner's preparatory  SDK for comparison of different scanner providers. It will make my system scanner manufacturer independent.

1. Is there any specific logic, algorithm or protocol for fingerprint comparison.
2. Is there any open-source PHP library available that I can go for FP comparison.

**Possible Clue**

I found some ppl saying, that I just need to compare the MD5 data of my RAW file, But I am not sure how would I be able to identify near match percentage like 80%+ is considered match. 100% match is not a practical thing in fingerprint.

Answer (score 2):

> after that at the time of verification I have to download all
>   fingerprints from server to mobile and use respective SDK to compare
>   one by one.

Dear god, no. I am glad you have identified this as needing improvement.

On to your questions:

> 1) Is there any specific logic, algorithm or protocol for fingerprint comparison.

Yes, there are many published algorithms for finger print processing.  Many of these processes have freely available algorithms: https://sourceafis.machinezoo.com/

> 2) Is there any open-source PHP library available that I can go for FP comparison.

Maybe, a quick google search turned up https://github.com/pushcodeveryday/Biometric-Fingerprint-Integration

As far as MD5 or other checksum based approaches go, they will all be guaranteed to fail as the image captured for each auth request will always vary by at least 1 bit.  Also, do not store the image as base64 in the database... that will increase the image storage requirement by ~50% for absolutely no reason. RDBMS' are designed for organizing data, not for file storage.  If you must use the database, use a freaking blob to store binary data instead of text, that's why the blob type exists.

Now that I have addressed your direct questions, lets talk about the why.  More specifically, why are you doing so much work to process these fingerprints in PHP?  It would be a lot easier to processes the fingerprint locally (in the app), and authorize the app with a shared secret that is generated when the user sets up their account in the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I need some time to review both link Will definitely accept as answer if it helped me. Now Why am I processing the fingerprints while I can authorise the user on client side. I'm actually not using FP for app lock, This is being used for user identity like in attendance system. Any user out of 1000 can come and use external fingerprint scanner and if that FP is there in my system API will reply with his identity. So I need to compare this user from all the users so client side not a good idea.

Comment: So What is understood is I should save ANSI/ISO Template of FP on server side, And I hope I would be able to compare FPs using MIT Licensed OpenSource Mantra's PHP SDK (Biometric-Fingerprint-Integration) on server side. @Alex Barker Do you have any correction or suggestions.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach, I was unaware that the app was shared.

Comment: Hello @Alex Barker I reviewed the PHP lib that you pointed out, But I found that MABIS (MANTRA AUTOMATED BIOMETRIC IDENTIFICATION SYSTEM) is not MIT Licence (OpenSource) and have to be purchased from Mantra (Other two MFS100 and MSI100V2 are client side SDK and can not be used on server side). So Now I am looking for the first option that you suggested (SourceAFIS - JAVA). What I am thinking to do is will deploy the JAVA SourceAFIS on my server machine and expose a API for matching. This API will be consumed by My PHP server running on same Machine via Local host URL.

Comment: @er.vish That is unfortunate.  I didn't find anything that was MIT licensed in PHP, but you could port (or call va [FFI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ffi.php)) a native mit library like https://github.com/ethiery/FuFengprint-Matcher.  There are several C/C++ options on github.